# Angular 4: How to navigate after login function without get token from api?

Tags: angular, api, authentication

The problem is: 
The API can use only with a GET-Request without token. I want to navigate after took the username and password.

Here the login code: 
**auth.service.ts**

```js
  login(BASE_URL, user): Promise<any>{
    // let p = new Promise(()=>{
      // localStorage.get('user').then((user)=>{
      let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':"Basic "+btoa(user.username+":"+user.password),
      })
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}`;
  // })

    return this.http.get(BASE_URL, options).toPromise();
  // })
}
```

Here the **login.component.ts**

```js
export class LoginComponent {
  user: User = new User();
  templateItems;
  username: String; 
  password: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, private auth: AuthService) {
    this.username = "";
    this.password = ""
  }

  onLogin(): void {
    this.auth.login('https://app.example/api/testabc', this.user)
    .then((user) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.json().auth_token);
      // this.router.navigateByUrl('/status');
      console.log(user.json());
      this.templateItems = user.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Here the **Status.ts**

```js
export class StatusComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      console.log(token)
      this.auth.ensureAuthenticated(token)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log(user.json());
        if (user.json().status === 'success') {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

For this project i use the following **Angular auth 4** Application 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/realpython/angular4-auth)

After the login is success i want to get the Data from APi in the other pages too. But i get 401 unauthorized response

Comment: Not sure what you've been trying to do but 401 means you don't attach your authentication token to request header, or the token is not correct as the one stored in your server.

Comment: when I log in, I get the data back from the server. But as soon as I get forwarded after that, the message 401 comes up. 
Can I navigate in my app without a token?  
What do I have to tell you that I have access to the data on every page of my app?

Comment: Are you sending the header `Authorization: \`Bearer ${token}\`` as part of the request that is responded with 401?

Comment: I fixed the problem. Thank you